# Merged Two Accounts. Duplicate Association Rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, merge-accounts

I just had my old and new Stack Overflow accounts merged recently. Before having them merged, I associated my *new* account with all the other sites. I went and looked today and found that after the merge I was no longer associated. I clicked on the associate button and was awarded 100 points, *again*, as I had not associated my old account with anything. I believe this was because of the difference in User IDs.

I'm guessing this will be erased on the next rep recalculation. Am I right?

Otherwise, just reporting a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug about  merge / re-associate I'll leave for Jeff et al.

I've just done a rep recalc on you SO and MSO accounts, and in both cases you *gained* 2 or 3 points (usually down to downvotes against deleted users/posts).

So no: you won't lose any points in the next rep recalc, unless the code changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're rep gets recalced you would likely lose the bonus from both. I have heard in the past that people got recalced and lost their association bonus, so I would imagine it would be double for you?

Comment: Oh great...

Comment: I don't think recalc loses the bonus unless there is a problem on the accounts...